# Filtering using REGEX failing in Big Data

Tags: bigdata

I have created a simple turtle file containing the following contents-

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<uri:uuid#1> rdfs:label "Communication"^^xsd:string .   
<uri:uuid#2> rdfs:label "Communication" .
```

Then I LOADED this turtle file in Big data.
After this I ran two select queries. The first one was-

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?x ?name ?datatype
WHERE {
 ?x rdfs:label  ?name .
 FILTER (STRSTARTS(?name,"Comm"))
 BIND(datatype(?name) as ?datatype)
}
```

This gave the following result-

```
     x          name           datatype
<uri:uuid#1>  Communication   xsd:string
<uri:uuid#2>  Communication   xsd:string
```

But when I ran a bit different query using REGEX in the FILTER like this-

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?x ?name ?datatype
WHERE {
 ?x rdfs:label  ?name .
 FILTER (regex(?name, "^Comm"))
 BIND(datatype(?name) as ?datatype)
}
```

the result was -

```
     x          name           datatype
<uri:uuid#2>  Communication   xsd:string
```

I was expecting the same result for both the SELECT query as in both cases ‘Communication’ is a string. 
Can you please let me know why the results are different, is it for the REGEX. If so then is it that in Big Data if a string is ‘strongly typed’ xsd:string then REGEX does not work.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got a solution for this. Regex actually works only on simple, untyped literals. To make the Regex work ?name needs to be wrapped around a str() operator. So the query needs to be-

```
SELECT ?x ?name ?datatype
WHERE {
?x rdfs:label ?name .
FILTER (regex(str(?name), "^Comm"))
BIND(datatype(?name) as ?datatype)
}
```

This will bring back both the triples.